# HttpContext.Current.User null with Web API v2 only project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My goal is to use IWA (Integrated Windows Authentication) with .NET Web API. I want to keep the project as just an Web API project, without MVC.

I created two projects in Visual Studio 2013 Premium:

1. The first I selected ASP.NET Web Application with Web API template with Authentication to Windows Authentication. This also includes ASP.NET MVC.
2. The second was an ASP.NET Web Application Empty template with core references for Web API.

The first one worked, I was able to get my account AD/Windows identity when calling:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User
```

The second I couldn't get my AD/Windows identity, I tried all of the following:

```
 - HttpContext.Current.User
 - User
 - RequestContext.Principal
```

What do I need to call from the Web API (second project) to populate the user?

Comment: I ran into this problem before as well. As far as I discovered there was no way to get the User from the Context in the WebAPI itself. What I ended up doing as a workaround was have the calling application (python) send the user credentials encrypted to the ApiController and then handled it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API v2 uses OWIN (Katana), to enable IWA with IIS you need to import the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb library.This uses IIS with the ASP.NET pipeline, which populates User.

Instructions to setup [OWIN with Web API](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana), notes:

1. This article is from 2013, since then Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb is no longer in pre-release, e.g. you don't need "-pre" to install from NuGet.
2. Remove the content inside the Configuration method of Startup.cs.